# RxJs not catching thrown errors

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am having issues with RxJs not catching exceptions from an observable stream.

Here is what my code looks like.

```
const Rx = require('rx');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('dotenv').load();
}

const getTransactionsVerificationStatus = (params, models, retryLimit = process.env.CARD_VERIFICATION_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT) => {
  const potCheckResult$ = models.pot().exists([params.userId, params.potId]);

  const needsVerified$ = models.transaction()
    .listUnverifiedCards([params.userId, params.potId])
    .map(card => {
      return {
        status: 'success',
        data: {
          card: {
            id: card.id,
            cardNumberMask: card.cardNumberMask,
            attemptsRemaining: (retryLimit - card.attempts),
            chargeDate: card.chargeDate,
            expiry: card.expiry,
            status: card.status
          },
          requiresVerification: true
        }
      };
    })
    .take(1);

  const verified$ = models.user()
    .getDefaultCard([params.userId])
    .map(card => {
      return {
        status: 'success',
        data: {
          card: {
            id: card.id,
            cardNumberMask: card.cardNumberMask,
            attemptsRemaining: (retryLimit - card.attempts),
            chargeDate: card.chargeDate,
            expiry: card.expiry,
            status: card.status
          },
          requiresVerification: false
        }
      };
    })
    .take(1);

  const error$ = potCheckResult$
    .filter(x => x.len <= 0)
    .map(() => {
      return {
        status: 'error',
        message: ['Requested pot does not exist for current user']
      };
    });

  return Rx.Observable
    .concat(error$, needsVerified$, verified$)
    .take(1)
    .catch(e => {
      logger.warn(e);

      return Rx.Observable.just(
        {
          status: 'error',
          type: 'array',
          data: ['Something went wrong']
        }
      );
    });
};

module.exports = getTransactionsVerificationStatus;
```

Essentially, there are three observable streams here, that are being merged with the `concat` method.

The problem is that if any of those models throws an exception, it is not caught by the `catch` method. How do I catch these exceptions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

For completeness, here are the tests I am running on the above code.

```
const chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-json-schema'));
const expect = chai.expect;
const getTransactionsVerificationStatus = require('../get-transactions-verification-status');
const Rx = require('rx');

describe('Get Transactions Verification Logic', function() {
  let models;

  beforeEach(function() {
    // Mock models
    models = (params) => {
      return {
        pot: () => {
          return {
            exists: () => {
              if(params.potExists) {
                return Rx.Observable.just({
                  len: params.potExists
                }).toArray()
              } else {
                return Rx.Observable.just({
                  len: 0
                });
              }
            }
          }
        },
        transaction: () => {
          return {
            listUnverifiedCards: () => {
              if(params.error) {
                throw new Error('This is an error!');
              }
              if (params.unverifiedCards) {
                return Rx.Observable.just({
                  id: "unverified card",
                  cardNumberMask: 123456,
                  attempts: 0,
                  chargeDate: null,
                  expiry: 2016123,
                  status: 'UNVERIFIED'
                });
              } else {
                return Rx.Observable.empty()
              }
            }
          };
        },
        user: () => {
          return {
            getDefaultCard: () => Rx.Observable.just(
              {
                id: "verified card",
                cardNumberMask: 123456,
                attempts: 0,
                chargeDate: null,
                expiry: 2016123,
                status: 'VERIFIED'
              }
            )
          };
        }
      };
    };
  });

  it('should return a non-verified card if one has been used in a transaction', done => {
    const params = {
      userId: 123,
      potId: 123
    };

    const modelParams = {
      potExists: 1,
      unverifiedCards: true
    };

    const response$ = getTransactionsVerificationStatus(
      params,
      models(modelParams),
      3
    );

    response$.subscribe(json => {
      expect(json).to.deep.equal({
        status: "success",
        data: {
          card: {
            id: "unverified card",
            cardNumberMask: 123456,
            attemptsRemaining: 3,
            chargeDate: null,
            expiry: 2016123,
            status: 'UNVERIFIED'
          },
          "requiresVerification": true
        }
      });
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should return the active card if no transactions have used an unverified card', done => {
    const params = {
      userId: 123,
      potId: 123
    };

    const modelParams = {
      potExists: 1,
      unverifiedCards: false
    };

    const response$ = getTransactionsVerificationStatus(
      params,
      models(modelParams),
      3
    );

    response$.subscribe(json => {
      expect(json).to.deep.equal({
        status: "success",
        data: {
          card: {
            id: "verified card",
            cardNumberMask: 123456,
            attemptsRemaining: 3,
            chargeDate: null,
            expiry: 2016123,
            status: 'VERIFIED'
          },
          "requiresVerification": false
        }
      });
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should return an error message if the user does not have a pot with the id requested', done => {
    const params = {
      userId: 1,
    };

    const modelParams = {
      potExists: 0,
      unverifiedCards: false,
      verifiedCards: false
    };

    const response$ = getTransactionsVerificationStatus(
      params,
      models(modelParams),
      3
    );

    response$.subscribe(json => {
      expect(json).to.deep.equal({
        status: 'error',
        message: ['Requested pot does not exist for current user']
      });
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should handle all other errors', done => {
    const params = {
      userId: 1,
    };

    const modelParams = {
      potExists: 1,
      unverifiedCards: true,
      error: true
    };

    const response$ = getTransactionsVerificationStatus(
      params,
      models(modelParams),
      3
    );

    response$.subscribe(json => {
      expect(json).to.deep.equal({
        status: 'error',
        type: 'array',
        data: ['Something went wrong']
      });
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

All of the above assertions pass except for the last one, which throws an error in the model, this error is never picked up and makes it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The issue was with the test, not the `getTransactionsVerificationStatus` function.

The problem was that the error I was throwing should have been thrown from with an observable. Here is the bit of code I updated.

```
  if (params.error) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(() => {
      throw new Error('Data error');
    });
  }
```

This was instead of

```
  if (params.error) {
    throw new Error('Data error');
  }
```

Hopefully someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On the stream you are concatenating, you have the take(1) operator, after the concat. This means that you will listen to the first value only. The take operator will then perform an implicit unsubscribe. This means that, if the first value is not an error, there will be no next event and thus no error for your 'catch' operator to catch.

Secondly, you are not subscribing to this stream in your example. Is this only in your code above or in real life as well. If you do not subscribe to your stream, the streams will not be started (as you are normally working with cold observables for what I'm seeing).

Comment: In this scenario, I only want one value. I either want a list of cards that are valid, a list that aren't or an error. The error is the most important item in this instance, which is why the error is the first item in the `concat` method.

The thing is that the error is making it to the browser.

The function is being exported and subscribed to in an other file.

I am currently using a mocha/chai test to artificially throw an error. Would it be useful if I included the tests?

Comment: Where are you throwing an error. In your map function of the errors$ you are returning an object and not throwing an error. Could this be the problem?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the issue. How would I catching it in the map function?

I thought the error should have bubbled up until it is caught though.

Comment: In your map you could just do 'throw new Error("message")' this way it should show up in your catch clause. Small jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/rofopoy/edit?js,console

Comment: Just tried, the error passes straight through and makes it back to the client. I've edited my original question to include the tests I am running. Perhaps they will be useful. You can see how I am throw the error.